# cannot access local variable 'conversation' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
@login_required
def detail(request, pk):
     
    conversation = Conversation.objects.filter(members__in=[request.user.id]).get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
          form = ConversationMessageForm(request.POST)

          if form.is_valid():
               conversation_message = form.save(commit=False)
               conversation_message.conversation = conversation
               conversation_message.created_by = request.user
               conversation_message.save()

               conversation.save()
          
               return redirect('conversation:detail',pk=pk)
    else:
         form = ConversationMessageForm()


    return render(request,'conversation/detail.html',{
          'conversation': conversation,
          'form': form,
     })
```

cannot access local variable 'conversation' where it is not associated with a value

Comment: In the code, a DoesNotExist error arises if there's no associated conversation. To handle this gracefully, consider employing a try/except block or the .first() method. Regardless of the value provided to the context, it remains accessible. Sometimes, when the value is None, it may render as an empty string, but it will always be available.